# Ruby on Rails: hidden field value not inserting into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two hidden_fields, `user_id` and `skill_id`

```
<%= form_for @skill do |s| %>
  <%= s.label :image, "Upload your skill" %>
  <%= s.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= s.hidden_field :skill_id, value: params[:id] %>
  <%= s.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller I have this:

```
def reviews
  @skill = Skill.new
end
```

I'm able to get the value for `skill_id` into my database, but I'm not able to get the value from `user_id`. In my rails console, I see that `user_id` is being passed through "skill", but doesn't show in my database.

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5+wxS929uxtt..", "skill"=>{"user_id"=>"7", "skill_id"=>"132", ...`

I even checked to see if I'm getting any value with `<%= current_user.id %>`, which I am.

Maybe someone can guide me to the right path in debugging this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Does your HTML shows the user ID correctly? Is the form field named correctly on the generated HTML?

Comment: Its showing as `"user_id"=>""` in your params that is why it is not getting passed to database.

Comment: Is your `user_id` set in the `attr_accessible`? Also I am assuming that a `skill` belongs to a `user`. Why not just use `@skill=current_user.skills.new` in your controller?

Comment: @fotanus yes its showing correctly and its show value too

Comment: @KirtiThorat sorry it was a typo. it shows a value id when I checked

Comment: Can you show the controller action that actually saves it?

Comment: @sonnyhe2002 its `@skill = Skill.new` that actually saves my form information

Comment: I dont understand, Skill.new does not commit it to the database, you will have to use @skill.save or something like that.

Comment: @sonnyhe2002 thats weird, cause I see my database expanding every time I'm testing the form out

Comment: Is it old data? Since you are using an existing skill_id then it was already there, BUT your reviews action have nothing to update it or save it.

Comment: Can you share your `routes.rb`? Are you sure that `reviews` action is called when you submit the form? Looking at the form it seems like `create` action of your controller would be called i.e., if your controller is RESTful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for @skill do |s| %>
   <%= s.label :image, "Upload your skill" %>
   <%= s.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
   <%= s.hidden_field :skill_id, value: params[:id] %>
   <%= s.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

This will go to the create action

So what you really want is to update an existing one since you are passing an existing skills id

```
def reviews
  @skill = Skill.find params[:id]
end
```

Now your form can use this

```
<%= form_for @skill do |s| %>
   <%= s.label :image, "Upload your skill" %>
   <%= s.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
   <%= s.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

It is now go to the update action, in your controller.

```
def update
  @skill = Skill.find params[:id]
  @skill.update_attributes params[:skill]
  redirect_to root_path # redirect to somewhere
end
```

Try this.

Comment: I don't think you're understand my questions

Comment: Your problem is that you cannot get user_id into the database. You can get the  user_id from the way above and then save it to your @skill. and do you   have any line like this  Skill.create params[:skill]

Comment: no, I have only `.new`. If I do .create, then my other fields don't get inputed unless I put it into create(params...)

Comment: Thanks, this and @Sean's answer got me in the right direction

Comment: Ok I updated my answer to have some kind of save in the database

Answer (score 1):

You need a create controller that would look something like this:

```
def create
  @skill = Skill.new(params[:skill])
  if @skill.save
    # Handle a successful save.
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

You may want to change the name of the `def reviews` controller to `def new`, and also add the new routes to `config/routes.rb`

Comment: this actually got me looking in the right direction... thanks